# Gap in Partial Residuals Plot for Logistic Regression Model

Tags: r, regression, logistic, data-visualization, residuals

I'm working on a logistic regression model using R with a binary outcome (prescribed DPP-4 inhibitors or other drugs) and several predictors. My model is specified as follows:

```
model_dpp4is <- glm(dpp4is_binary ~ age + sex + year_of_rx_fill + bmi + dgf + creatinine + 
                    esw + insulin_at_start + log_time_since_transplantation + 
                    dgf:creatinine:log_time_since_transplantation + CongestiveHeartFailure + 
                    LiverDisease, 
                  data = dt, family = binomial)
```

After fitting the model, I generated partial residuals plots for my continuous variables and observed a peculiar pattern. There is a noticeable gap around the zero line in these plots, with a clustering of values above and very few spread below, indicating a threshold that the residuals do not cross. Here's an example plot for BMI:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0VzxW.png

I cannot share the dataset, but here are some details about the variables involved:

```
Outcome Variable (Binary): DPP-4 inhibitors (1) vs. other drugs (0)
    Proportion of cases: 10% DPP-4 inhibitors (n= 1935), 90% other drugs (n = 17190)

Continuous Predictors:
    Age (rage): Range = [18, 87], Mean = 56.64, Median = 58, 1st Qu. = 49, 3rd Qu. = 66
    Year of prescription fill (year_of_rx_fill): Range = [2014, 2020], Mean = 2017, Median = 2017, 1st Qu. = 2016, 3rd Qu. = 2019
    BMI (bmi): Range = [13.00, 56.13], Mean = 29.50, Median = 29.27, 1st Qu. = 25.79, 3rd Qu. = 33.15
    Serum Creatinine (mrcreat): Range = [0.36, 24.67], Mean = 3.94, Median = 2.91, 1st Qu. = 1.58, 3rd Qu. = 5.70
    Log time since transplantation (log_time_since_transplantation): Range = [0.000, 8.465], Mean = 3.727, Median = 3.258, 1st Qu. = 1.792, 3rd Qu. = 5.645

Categorical Predictors:
    Sex (rfemale): 6852 Female, 12273 Male
    Delayed graft function (dgf): 5691 Yes, 13434 No
    Early steroid withdrawal (esw): 5268 Yes, 13857 No
    Insulin use at start (insulin_at_start): 1229 users, 17880 non-users
    Congestive Heart Failure (C_CongestiveHeartFailure): 5853 Yes, 13272 No
    Mild Liver Disease (C_MildLiverDisease): 8171 Yes, 10954 No

Categorical Predictors:
    Gender: 40% female, 60% male
    Congestive Heart Failure: 15% yes, 85% no
    Mild Liver Disease: 10% yes, 90% no
    (Include frequency for other categorical predictors)
```

```
This strange gap around the 0 line exists in all of my partial residual plots for my numeric and categorical variables.

My questions are:

    

 1. Why might these gaps around the zero line be occurring?
 2. What steps can I take to diagnose and address this issue in my model?

    


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jwxv.png
```

Comment: Intepreting residual plots in GLMs is not always straight forward. Are you aware of the DHARMa package?  https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/DHARMa/vignettes/DHARMa.html

Comment: I haven't but will look in to this. Thank you

Comment: The gap a the zero horizontal line is a well known pattern of logistic regression residuals, due to the fact that the model predicts an outcome of y = 0 or 1 with a probability p, which is a real value between 0 and 1. Since the residuals are proportional to (y - p), they are positive when y = 1 and negative when y = 0 and this produces the separation around zero,. The above means that the points below 0 are the points with y = 0 and the points above 0 correspond to y = 1. More details can be found in the following post: https://www.r-bloggers.com/2013/08/residuals-from-a-logistic-regression.

Comment: Thank you so much @mastropi! This solves my question.